# Is there any way of animating a smooth transition between the original html of an element and its AJAX replacement in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, animation, jquery-animate

I'm using jQuery and AJAX to replace the preview of a post with its full text when it's clicked on.

```
function loadFullPost(permalink, divID, postID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: permalink + "?ajax=true",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#" + divID + "").addClass("full").removeClass("preview").html(result);
            loadComments(divID, postID);
        }
    })
}
```

This works, but currently the HTML in the div is instantly replaced.

I know about jQuery animations in general, but fading out the original result and then fading in the result loaded via AJAX causing a flicker where for a moment there's nothing on screen.

Is there any way of creating an animation that smoothly animates between the two sets of html, much like a Fade effect between two slides in Powerpoint?

Comment: I guess you will need two identical DOM elements (or set of elements), one for fading out the old content and one for fading in the new one. Once the animation is done, you can safely remove the element that was carrying the previous faded out content entirely.